# How to get thumbnail for video from PHAsset?

Tags: swift, phasset

I am trying to populate aa UICollectionView with thumbnails of videos and photos extracted from the user's camera roll. I loaded all the media from the camera roll in the form of `PHAsset` inside the array `images` as declared here:

`var images = [PHAsset]()`

The `if-then` loop checks to see if the `PHAsset` is either a image or a video. If it is a image, it simply adds it to the collection view. However, I am not sure how I would add a thumbnail of a video to the collection view. Any help is appreciated.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell
    let asset = images[indexPath.row]

    if asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 138, height: 138), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
        cell.imageView.image = thumbnail
    } else {
        // code to add the thumbnail of the video to the collection view
    }

    return cell
  }
```

Edit:
I tried removing the if-then method but the collection view shows no thumbnail for the videos at all.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell

    let asset = images[indexPath.row]
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 138, height: 138), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })
    cell.imageView.image = thumbnail

    return cell
}
```

If you look at the link below, I clearly have a video in my camera roll but it doesn't show up in the collection view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIP8W.jpg

Comment: Have you tried doing the same for videos as you already are for photos? The documentation suggests that both video and photo assets have a thumbnail property available from PHImageManager.

Comment: @JoshHeald I have tried but it shows up as a blank image for some odd reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using PHAsset `requestImage(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:)` works for both Photos and Videos.

[From Apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimage)

> You can use this method for both photo and video assets for a video
>   asset, an image request provides a thumbnail image or poster frame.

So just drop the if statement and call request the thumbnail for both types.

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 138, height: 138), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
        cell.imageView.image = thumbnail
```

Edit:
Make sure network access is allowed

```
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
```

Comment: Tried doing this, see the code in the updated post. The collection view doesn't show the thumbnail at all in result.

Comment: I also added some pictures for reference

Comment: @itsfaraaz make sure network access is allowed. see my edits

Comment: Still no luck, see my updated code for the edit I made.

Comment: @itsfaraaz can you share the code you use to fetch the camera roll too?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. When I was fetching assets, I only fetched PHAssetMediaType.image. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @itsfaraaz glad you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use `PHCachingImageManager` as in [Apple sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
let cachingImageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
```

and somewhere before loading the items call try to load the caches

```
func updateCache() {
    //Update the size here
    let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 138, height: 138)

    cachingImageManager.startCachingImages(for: images, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil)
}
```

then loading the thumbnail for images and videos would be like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell

    let asset = images[indexPath.row]

    let size = CGSize(width: 138, height: 138)

    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    option.isSynchronous = true

    cachingImageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { image, info in
        cell.imageView.image = image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Note: loading the images from the `PHAsset` without cacheing might lead to a memory issue

you might need to create another `PHCachingImageManager` in case of items change in the images array